# how to find shortest simple cycles in directed graph that contain two given nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, directed-graphs

*this problem can be NP-hard

I am looking for algorithm to find shortest simple cycle (every node in cycle is traversed exactly once) in directed (unweighted for simplicity) graph that contain two given nodes, also it would be nice to have polynomial time instead bruteforce-like solutions (although some NP solutions with good optimizations may be valuable)

one idea is to use Dijkstra and in second step "inverted" Dijkstra although, after normal Dijkstra removing traversed arcs/edges may disconnect graph which should contain cycle for given nodes,

any ideas would be welcome

Answer (score 4):

**Input:** A digraph $G=(V,E)$ and two vertices $u,v \in V$.

**Output:** The shortest simple directed cycle in $G$ containing $u$ and $v$.

I am not sure if we could use a 2-disjoint shortest path approach for the directed case as well (a version in which we find a shortest path from $u$ to $v$ and one from $v$ to $u$ and these paths are disjoint). This problem seems to be $\mathcal{NP}$-hard in general for directed graphs, but I am not sure. There might be a neat solution.

However, we could use [Johnson's algorithm](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0204007). It numbers the vertices from $1$ to $|V|$ and finds all cycles containing the smallest numbered vertex, and continues with the next one and so on. So we modify it such that our vertex $u$ receives the smallest number and we only iterate over the cycles containing $u$. While doing so, we keep track of the lengths of each such cycle and if a cycle contains $v$ we temporarily store it to some variable $C$. In each iteration we compare the length of each new match (that is a cycle containing $u$ and $v$) with the length of $C$  and if it is smaller, we replace the value of $C$ with the new cycle. We do that for each cycle. Then return $C$.

Johnson's algorithm is implemented in [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html) and you could fork their implementation from [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/cycles.py). Johnson's algorithm is implemented in the method "simple_cycles(G)".

**Input:** An undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and two vertices $u,v \in V$.

**Output:** The shortest simple cycle in $G$ containing $u$ and $v$.

This works for undirected graphs. We translate the undirected graph into its directed version (replace each undirected each by two directed edges being inverse to each other) and use [Suurballe‘s algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm) exploiting the fact that the union of two shortest disjoint paths with the same endpoints form a shortest cycle in an undirected graph. It finds two edge disjoint shortest paths between two vertices $u$ and $v$ by running Dijsktra‘s algorithm twice.

There is a nice running example in [this](http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Disjoint_Path_Finding) article.

Notice that standard Suurballe is not necessarily vertex disjoint but we can modify it as described in both provided articles:

> The version of Suurballe's algorithm as described above finds paths that have disjoint edges, but that may share vertices. It is possible to use the same algorithm to find vertex-disjoint paths, by replacing each vertex by a pair of adjacent vertices, one with all of the incoming adjacencies u-in of the original vertex, and one with all of the outgoing adjacencies u-out.

Comment: thank you for answer, I just realized that simple cycles node disjoint version suits better my initial problem

Comment: also what if in wiki's example there is no arc $DB$? is it possible to find cycle in this way?

Comment: I am not quite sure what your thoughts are for this one. If $DB$ is missing, then the algorithm will of course find a different cycle. The algorithm works in general.

Comment: true - my mistake, although it finds two different paths, what if these paths are only one-directional? it can't find cycle then..., maybe I defined problem in a way that suggested that paths can be bi-directional, for example in digraph that can be sorted topologically we can't find cycles with first and last nodes

Comment: Yes, then no cycle is found, because there is none. A directed cycle  is a finite (or infinite) sequence of edges **directed** in the **same direction** which joins a sequence of vertices.

Comment: If all your paths in your directed graph are bidirectional, then this is equivalent of an undirected graph (for each directed edge there is an undirected edge in inverse direction with the same endpoints).

Comment: yes but I understand from your answer that if this algorithm will find two paths (both same orientation) then we are set because we can create cycle, sorry for my comment but probably I don't see something that might be trivial for you. In essence finding path with Dijkstra and removing these edges can disconnect path in reverse direction, but finding less optimal path in 1 step would allow to keep path that is answer in step 2, maybe it's $NP-complete$ like $TSP$ problem

Comment: I had my head elsewhere. I added some more ideas. But this might be incomplete or not a neat solution. I am sorry for the inconvinience